# Help finding out details of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

So i have this function:
$$f(x)= (2-x)e^{-\sqrt{1-x}}$$

And it's domain is $x\leq 1$ if investigated that correctly.
Now i am confused about it's codomain, i came to an assumption it's $y\in(0,1]$
But is it really accurate enough?
I am trying to draw it with using derivatives, but i guess this part is important as well, i'm presuming it won't be even nor odd function because of the exponential part.
I will use only 1st and 2nd derivative so that shouldn't be a problem.
So my main question is if i did the codomain and domain part correctly 
Thank you in advance.

Edit: i got the first derivative  like this:
$$f'(x)=2(-x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{(-x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

If someone can check it it would be great, cause i feel like it could be wrong, but well this function seems like it won't have any zeros at this domain.

Comment: You have obtained the correct domain and codomain. With respect to the codomain note that $2-x$ and $e^{-\sqrt{1-x}}$ are positive and increasing in $(-\infty,1].$ So, its product is positive and increasing. Since they are positive you have $f>0.$ Since they are increasing $f$ is increasing. So, its maximum is $f(1)=1.$

Comment: @mfl thank you. i added something to the question, if its possible to check it?

Comment: The first derivative is $$f'(x)=-e^{\sqrt{1-x}}+\frac{2-x}{2\sqrt{1-x}}e^{-\sqrt{1-x}}=\left(\frac{2-x}{2\sqrt{1-x}}-1\right)e^{-\sqrt{1-x}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = \sqrt{1-x}\implies u^2 = 1- x \implies x = 1-u^2\implies 2-x = 1+u^2\implies f(x) = f(u) = (1+u^2)e^{-u}\implies f'(u) = 2ue^{-u} - (1+u^2)e^{-u}= -e^{-u}(1-u)^2\le 0\implies f(x) = f(u)\le f(0) = 1$ which is the maximum of $f$. Next, let $c \in (0,1)$ be any real number, we show the equation $c = (1+u^2)e^{-u}$ has at least a solution $u \in (0,\infty)$. The function $f(u) = 1+u^2 - ce^{u}$ has $f(0) = 1 - c > 0$, and since $f$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and $f(u) \to -\infty $ when $u \to \infty$, there exists a real number $x_0 > 0$ such that $f(x_0) < 0$. Thus the Intermediate-Value Theorem says that $f(u) = 0$ for some $u \in (0,x_0)$. This shows $c$ is in the range of $f$, and we conclude that the range of $f$ is the set $\{y: y \in \mathbb{R}, 0 <  y \le 1 \}$.